# Send a variable to HTML with express sendfile (short question)

Tags: javascript, html, express, path

I'm using Node.JS, path, and express to run an HTML webpage and need to send a variable to the HTML for its use:

```
var client_cred_access_token = 'fakeToken';

...

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'homepage.html'));
});
```

How can I send this string variable to homepage.html?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a template engine middleware like pug / ejs with express to achieve this functionality.

Sample code with ejs library. Just `npm i ejs`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = new express;
const path = require('path');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

const client_cred_access_token = 'fakeToken';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'homepage.html'), {token: client_cred_access_token});
});

app.listen(3001);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><%= token %></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use EJS as it conflicts with other files in the system. I have seen that answer in the past, so I appreciate it.

Comment: @RhettJarvis how about the other template engines from the list?